# AngularJS with route and JSON API

Tags: javascript, json

I tried to use AngularJS with the plugin JSON API. I have no error but the route doesn't work, and the page doesn't print the partials/... ?

I changed the permalinks to `%postName%`.

I use MAMP and my link is: `http://localhost:8888/angular-wp`.

The JSON content works: `http://localhost:8888/angular-wp/api/get_posts/`

The routeScope had two values empty.

**main.html**

```
<p>main</p>
<a href='/demo'>This links to /demo</a>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='post in posts'>
    <a href='{{post.slug}}'>{{post.title}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**demo.php**

```
{{post.content}}
<p>demo :)</p>
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' ng-app='app'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <title>hooo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>
      <a href='/'>Worcamp 2014</a>
    </h1>
  </header>

  <div ng-view>TODO: have angular infect the content here via ajax</div>

  <footer>&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> worcamp</footer>

  <script src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/bower_components/angular/angular.js'></script>
  <script src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  <?php $pathTheme = get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
  angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          templateUrl: '<?php echo $pathTheme; ?>/partials/main.html',
            controller: 'Main'
        })
        .when('/:slug', {
          templateurl:  
            '<?php echo $pathTheme; ?>/partials/demo.php',
            controller: 'Slug'
        });
        //.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
      })
      .controller('Main', function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
        $http.get('/api/get_posts/').success(function(res) {
          $scope.posts = res.posts;
        });
      })
      .controller('Slug', function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
        $http.get('/api/get_posts/?slug=' + $routeParams.slug).success(function(res) {
          $scope.post = res.post;
        });
      });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doublecheck if there’s a “nobase” error in your console. If so, according to the AngularJS documentation, and [fix.io](https://1fix.io/blog/2014/11/05/angularjs-json-api-wp-theme/) (credits for this answer go to [the author of that post](https://1fix.io/blog/author/admin/)) the base tag is to the rescue.

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <base href="/angular-wp/">
    <title>AngularJS Demo Theme</title>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Please note the “/angular-wp/” is the sub-context in this case (the test url is like “http://localhost/angular-wp/”), you should replace it accordingly. If you set the wrong base href, you’ll get an [error like this](https://1fix.io/blog/2014/11/05/angularjs-json-api-wp-theme/#comment-6494) or [this](https://1fix.io/blog/2014/11/05/angularjs-json-api-wp-theme/#comment-6562).

Answer (score 0):

If you think about switching the Plugin: I did used "WP REST API" Plugin (wich implements [WP API](http://wp-api.org/)) and then `$http.get('WPURL/wp-json/posts', function (data, ...) {...})`, that worked perfect.

You get the Posts featured image for example via `data[post-index].featured_image.source`, see all properties via `console.log(data[0])`.